# Postgresql decimal point using to_char

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-char

I want make a select that adds decimal point into integers, but when I do it, it shows me bunch of # instead of those numbers.

```
SELECT to_char(1234, '99.99');
```

What I expected was table with a value of 12.34 but I got ##.## in my select.
However, if I did

```
SELECT to_char(1234, '99,99');
```

it showed be 12,34 as expected. Problem is, that I want to have a decimal point and not a comma.
I am using PostgreSQL 13.2

Comment: That makes no sense. 1234 has no digits after the decimal point. It would work for 12.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to take the last 2 digits and pretend they were decimals. You can't use the predefined `.` or `D` formats because they apply to true decimals.

Instead, you can print the dot character (like any other string), between double quotes, before the last 2 digits:

```sql
 SELECT to_char(1234, '999"."99');
 to_char
---------
   12.34
```

PS: on a side note, you are getting the masked output in your 1st query because there isn't enough digit positions on the format:

```sql
 SELECT to_char(1234, '9999.99');
 to_char
----------
  1234.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You were very close:) Which locale are you using? Check this example for `en_US.UTF-8`:

```
SELECT to_char(1234, '999G99');
 to_char 
---------
   12.34
(1 row)
```

- `G`: Group separator that uses **locale**
- `D`: Decimal point that uses **locale**

Check this [`tutorial`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/)

Comment: I tried your select, and it says "12NBSP34" or just "12 34" with a space in between.
If you mean numeric locale, then I use Slovak_Slovakia.1250

Comment: I see, this one I couldn't predict :D But as I can see, the post from JGH already answers your question. Cheers :)